# elementary matrix - single element change

Tags: matrix-equations

I have a question on how to get matrix B from matrix A.

```
A =   1 2 3 4 5 
      6 7 8 9 10
      0 0 1 0 0

B is given, too

B = 6 7 0 9 10
    1 2 0 4 5
    0 0 1 0 0
```

the tools are swapping, adding and multiplying individual lines to one another. main problem here: how to get these 0s in line 1 and 2 is not obvious for me in B.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First swap the first and second rows to get 
$\begin{pmatrix}6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Then subtract 8 times the third row from the first row and subtract 3 times the third row from the second row.

Comment: They probably wrote the question wrong, but note that you wouldn't be able to subtract with the operations that they wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 3rd row to clear the 3rd column except the bottom entry then swap the 1st & 2nd row, period.

Answer (score 1):

If the valid operations are '`swapping, adding and multiplying individual lines to one another`', then it is **impossible** to get the matrix $B$ from matrix $A$. note that these operations can only increase the total sum of all the elements.

However, **these are not the only operations allowed** by multiplication by elementary matrices. Elementary transformation allow you to add to a row, another row multiplied by a number. This operation would allow you to add to the first row, the last row multiplied by $-1$. This is, subtract the last row from the first row. Likewise, you can subtract the last row from the second row. Finally swap the first two rows to get $B$.

Comment: multiplying 3rd row with -1. okay. I undertand the approach. But I need a -8 for cancellig out the (2,3) and a -3 cancelling out (1,3). So I would have to multiply the last row by -3 and by -8.  This does not work out, once the last row is changed, I guess.

Comment: @HiDuEi The operation doesn't change the row being subtracted. It only changes the row to which it is being subtracted. In other words if the rows are $R_1,R_3$ then new rows would be $R_1-8R_2, R_3$. Note how $R_3$ stays the same.